# Update a MySQL on a from a mapping values on another table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a SQL table with a column that has unnormalized values, E.G:

```
City: 'City 1', 'City one', 'City 2/ some text'....
```

I have the correct mapping of values which will be:

```
'City 1':'City 1' ,
'City one':'City 1',
'City 3/ some text':'City 3'
```

the list is around 100 cases, in python I would just use a dict, but I don't know how to do this in SQL

I found the following example: https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/replacing-a-case-statement-in-an-update-with-table-driven-logic

And tried to follow it like:

```
UPDATE dbo.target_table
set city =

case

when city   = 'City 1' then 'City 1' 
when city   = 'City one' then 'City 1'

END
```

but ended up with the city column being empty instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need an `else`:

```
update dbo.target_table
    set city = (case when city   = 'City 1' then 'City 1' 
                     when city   = 'City one' then 'City 1'
                     else city
                end)
```

Or, better yet, a `where` clause:

```
update dbo.target_table
    set city = (case when city   = 'City 1' then 'City 1' 
                     when city   = 'City one' then 'City 1'
                     else city
                end) 
    where city in ('City 1', 'City one');
```